# Url helper vs Anchor Tag in ASP.Net Core Razor Pages

Tags: asp.net-core, razor-pages

What is the difference between the `Url` helper and Anchor Tag in ASP.Net Core Razor Pages?

For example, I would have the same result in both.

Please see:

```
@page "{name}/{rating?}"
@model WebApplication6.Pages.CityModel
@{
}

<a href="@Url.Page("/Logout",new { logoutId = 1 })">Logout</a>
<br/>
<a asp-page="/Logout" asp-route-logoutId="1">Logout</a>
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: There is no difference

But what is the purpose of anchor tags?

According to the Microsoft document : [Anchor Tag Helper in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/built-in/anchor-tag-helper?view=aspnetcore-7.0)

> The Anchor Tag Helper enhances the standard HTML anchor (<a ... >) tag by adding new attributes. By convention, the attribute names are prefixed with asp-. The rendered anchor element's href attribute value is determined by the values of the asp- attributes.

But imagine that you want to create a page address for a scenario in your controller, that you cannot write code in `Razor syntax` so there you no longer have access to `Anchor Tags` and you only have to use `C# syntax`

Conclusion:

On razor pages, try to use `Anchor Tags` that are closer to the `HTML` standard. But for somewhere other than `Razor Pages`. If you do not have access to `Anchor Tags`, use [UrlHelperExtensions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.urlhelperextensions.page?view=aspnetcore-7.0)